# Adapt latex page header depending on situations

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I added a page header with the following command in LaTeX:

```
\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark} \fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  

\title{Titlepage}
\date{October 2021}

\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark} \fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase CHAPTER}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
  {{\chapnamefont}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
      \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thesection}%
      \hspace{.8em}%
      \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
    }%
  }%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
blank page
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
the page header should not be visible here

\newpage

\subsection{Test2}
only the section should be visible in the page header (1 INTODUCTION) 

\newpage
only the subsection should be visible in the page header (1.1 Test2) 

\end{document}
```

With this command there is the problem that it appears on all pages, but for my thesis I would like to remove it from pages where the section shows up for the first time

here is an example how it currently looks:
[image: current style page header]

this is how it should look like, when the section appears for the first time:
[image: how it should look like]

Also I would like the header to adapt, according to which side it is on (even or odd). For example I would want to have on the left page the section name only (even page) and on the right side the subsection name should show up (odd page):
[image: different section depending on page]

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, just added one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use another documentclass. This would automatically solve most of your problems:

- in report or book class, the first pages of a chapter automatically use another page style without the header
- if you use a two-sided document, you can define the fancyhead depending on `E`(ven) or `O`(dd) pages

---

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  

\title{Titlepage}
\date{October 2021}

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to generate text for the example

\newcommand*\HUGE{\Huge}
\newcommand*\chapnamefont{\normalfont\LARGE\MakeUppercase CHAPTER}
\newcommand*\chapnumfont{\normalfont\HUGE}
\newcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries}

\newlength\beforechapskip
\newlength\midchapskip
\setlength\midchapskip{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\midchapskip{-1in}
\setlength\beforechapskip{18mm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filleft}
  {{\chapnamefont}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
      \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
      \hspace{.8em}%
      \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
    }%
  }%
  {25pt}
  {\chaptitlefont}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
blank page
\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}
the page header should not be visible here

\newpage

\section{Test2}
only the section should be visible in the page header (1 INTODUCTION) 

\newpage
only the subsection should be visible in the page header (1.1 Test2) 

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi, changing it to report fixed the issues, thanks a lot! btw. is there also an option to remove the page header from pages without any section? for example so that in the table of content there are no page header or when a chapter is defined without any section? thanks for the help already!

Comment: @igotPOWA You can use `\thispagestyle{plain}` or `empty` on these pages

Comment: worked out, thanks!